# Operations after committing a transaction in spring

Tags: spring, transactions, locks

I have a situation in Spring where I am writing data to some external source, 
Now before writing the data to the external source,

1. i take a lock
2. read the object
3. perform some operation
4. write the oject back. and unlock the object.

---

Below piece of code explaing roughly how i do it.

//Code begins here

```
Lock lck = new ReentrantLock();

public void manipulateData(){

lck.lock();
//Object obj = read the data
//modify it

Write(obj)
lck.unlock();

}
```

//Code End here

Now in a multi-threaded environment what currently happens is after write call I am calling unlock but my transaction is not committed until my function execution completes. However since I am calling unlock. Other thread gets the lock and read the data which is actually in correct.

So I want something like the lock should be obtained by other thread only when the transaction commit.

Also I cannot use programmatic transaction.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider extracting the code that reads the object and modifies it to a different method (annotated with `@Transactional`). The lock should then be taken just before invoking the method and released after the method returns. Something like this:

```
@Autowired
private Dao dao;

public void manipulateData(){

    lck.lock();
    dao.update(myObj);
    lck.unlock();
}

class Dao {

    @Transactional
    public void update(MyObject obj) {
        //read and modify
    }
}
```

Comment: The thing is the manipulateData is called from some other class from where the transcaion starts and i cannot change that code. Hence every function is called under the context of a transaction :(

Comment: Also i cannot afford to make the write(obj) call without a transaction.

Comment: That is a strange design. Can you elaborate why do you want to lock the object? Because if you are worried about a concurrent thread reading uncommitted state of object, then that is taken care by transaction isolation itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement an Aspect (AOP) similar to this:

First create a proprietary Transactional similar to this:

```
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface LockingTransactional {
}
```

Then the aspect's interesting code should be similar to this:

```
    ...
    private final Lock lck = new ReentrantLock();
    ...

    @Around("@annotation(<FULL-PACKAGE-NAME-HERE>.LockingTransactional)")
    public Object intercept(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        try {
            lck.lock();
            TransactionStatus status = createTransaction(); // create the transaction "manually"
            Object result;
            try {
                result = pjp.proceed();
            } catch (Throwable t) { 
                txManager.rollback(status);
                throw t;
            }
            txManager.commit(status);
            return result;
        } finally {
            lck.unlock();
        }
    }

...

    private TransactionStatus createTransaction() {
        DefaultTransactionDefinition definition = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
        def.setIsolationLevel(<YOUR-LEVEL-HERE>);
        def.setPropagationBehavior(<YOUR-PROPAGATION-HERE>);
        return txManager.getTransaction(definition);
    }

...
```